# java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind (JBOSS)

Tags: java, windows-7, jboss, jakarta-ee, jvm

I'm using JBoss 4.0.5 GA on Windows 7 with Java version 1.5 (I have to use older java version and a JBoss because I'm working with a legacy system). And when I'm starting the server I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
```

And I believe this causes many other exceptions:

```
11:09:26,925 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting servicejboss.cache:service=TomcatClustering Cache
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.down(FD_SOCK.java:235)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.down(FD.java:278)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.down(Protocol.java:540)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.down(NAKACK.java:297)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST.down(UNICAST.java:262)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.down(STABLE.java:292)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.down(GMS.java:605)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FC.down(FC.java:122)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.down(FRAG2.java:146)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passDown(Protocol.java:510)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.down(STATE_TRANSFER.java:217)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.receiveDownEvent(Protocol.java:467)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.down(ProtocolStack.java:331)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.down(JChannel.java:1035)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:374)
    at org.jboss.cache.TreeCache.startService(TreeCache.java:1424)
    at org.jboss.cache.aop.PojoCache.startService(PojoCache.java:94)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I greatly appreciate if anyone could help. At least to figure out where I should look for the solution (e.g. Is this an error related to windows 7 and JBoss clustering incompatability? Is this because of a wrong port configuration? etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: I had to swtich my OS to find a quick solution. So if someone could please point me out if there's a solution among the current answers. then I'll mark it as the answer for the benefit of the community.

Comment: I have the same error, but it has appeared by itself. Selenium used to work, and now it fails to start. Surely a reboot of Windows will fix this, but I am looking for a nicer solution. Relaunching Eclipse was not enough.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This problem occurs on some Windows systems that have the IPv6 TCP Stack installed. If both IPv4 and IPv6 are installed on the computer, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) may have problems closing or opening sockets at the operating system level.

Add the following JVM option: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

I've seen this happen on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 systems which have both IPv4 and IPv6 stacks installed by default.

Comment: You sir are my hero.  I was running a non-JBoss application, but this fixed it up lickity split

Comment: How/Where would you add the JVM option?

Comment: Voting up even though it didn't help me, because this way Java gives a more informative error when it fails :)

Comment: Where to set JVM Option. can u tell me location of file

Comment: To add more, you can add JVM option in building jar, `sbt clean assembly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Judging by the responses, this seems likely the correct answer. Unfortunately, I did not have the chance to revisit the problem and validate. So I'm trusting the commenters and other answers.

Answer (score 15):

You have very likely another process already bound on a port that JBoss is using (8080?) and this prevent JBoss from starting correctly (see [this page](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/JBoss+Ports) for a list of ports used by JBoss).

Either find the conflicting process and shut it down:

- use `netstat -a -o -n` and look for ports used by JBoss (e.g. 8080) and the corresponding `pid`
- then use `tasklist /FI "PID eq <pid>"` to find the process

Or change JBoss defaults ports. There are several ways to do that but the best way is to use the [Service Binding Manager](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ServiceBindingManager) (see detailed instructions in [Configuring Multiple JBoss Instances On One Machine](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine)).

Comment: Hi Pascal, Unfortunately that way did not work. There's no other processes using the port 8080 (my JBoss using 8080). I had to switch my O/S to work with that specific app.

Comment: @Shamal Weird, very weird. Sorry it didn't help in your particular case.

Comment: I have not found the answer for this yet. I had to work on Windows XP to solve the problem. It seems this is some incompatibility with windows 7 port system?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. I used [process-xp](http://www.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and kill `javaw.exe`, then restart the application. It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue on Win7 trying to implement the example here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

The default port in the example code is 4444. Using this port I got
"Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind"

I changed the port to 44444 and tried again.  I got a popup from the Windows Firewall service asking me if this application had permission to access the network.  Selecting OK I no longer get the error message when I launch my server.

After some experimenting I found that with a port of 5000 or less I would get the JVM_Bind error.  Any port of 5001 or above would bind without issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's problem of JAVA 32/64 bit. try run your jar with 32 bit JVM

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with my Tomcat and it turned to be a port conflict with Skype. In my Skype->Options->Advanced->Connection I unchecked the following "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections". This solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 2):

this solved my problem :) Add the following JVM option: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 2):

open command prompt as administrator. Then do a **netsh winsock reset**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Tomcat on Windows 10.  Added this to the catalina.bat file near the top:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but I've just recently figured out one cause of the issue, as well as the solution. My server socket program worked fine until I put the code into a loop, then I got the error `Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind` on every attempt to `accept()` after the first attempt. I had code like this:

```
ServerSocket ssock = null;
Socket sock = null;

while (loopCount < loopLimit) {
    ssock = new ServerSocket(port);
    ssock.setSOLimit(millis);
    sock = ssock.accept();
    // some code here...
    loopCount++;
}
```

It was only when I put `ssock = new ServerSocket(port)` and  `ssock.setSOLimit(millis);` above the loop that I eliminated the error.

Answer (score 0):

I hade to add SystemRoot parameter in java parameters. I dont don't know why java doesn't have this parameter. It was working before. With

> SystemRoot=C:\Windows

it works.
I execute the java as Windows service nssm.