# My server application doesn't work on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

when I run my server application on eclipse it doesn't work and the error is shown as following:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:26)
```

Comment: Can we see your MyServer code? becuase it's hard to debug if theres no code

Comment: It seems like your server trying to run on port which is already been bold by some other server or application.

Comment: @Harry Joy usually the error message for that is "port already in use" is it not??

Comment: Yeah, you usually see `Adress already in use: JVM_BIND` if the port is already bound.

Comment: Not answered but seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947555/java-net-socketexception-unrecognized-windows-sockets-error-0-jvm-bind-jboss). You use Windows 7?

Comment: @RMT: I apologize. It was my mistake. The message for that is not the same as this one.

Comment: thank to all, when I changed port number  the server worked well.

Comment: @user875264: You did not get the root cause, I'm interested...?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to initialize the port and you are trying to connect to port=0 that is invalid. I thing that your application receives port via command line. When you are running it from eclipse you forgot to provide it. Do it using the run/debug configuration.

It is just a theory. I do not see your code.