# JDBC The Network Adapter could not establish the connection/Connection reset/recv failed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish, timeout

I currently have a application running that needs data from a database to be able to work properly.

Here are the specifics:

- Glassfish 3.1.2
- Oracle DB 11.2.0.2.0 (I have limited access here)
- Java 7/JEE6
- JDBC Lib oracle-jdbc-11.2.0.3-jdk6.jar
- I use pooling with a standard configuration by Glassfish when a new connection pool is created
- The SQLs used are only selects with no joins or other complex structures within
- They run easily under 30 sec and below depending on the SQL

My problem is that I get the following error messages in infrequent intervals which results in missing data or complete shutdown of the JDBC resource.

```
[#|2015-10-22T16:25:42.400+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=461;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool jdbc. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection|#]
```

Followed by

```
[#|2015-10-22T19:10:47.787+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool|_ThreadID=461;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5035:Unexpected exception while destroying resource from pool jdbc. Exception message: Error while destroying resource :I/O-Fehler: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed|#]
[#|2015-10-22T19:10:48.052+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool|_ThreadID=461;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5035:Unexpected exception while destroying resource from pool jdbc. Exception message: Error while destroying resource :I/O-Fehler: Connection reset|#]
```

Followed by

```
 [#|2015-10-22T19:11:33.287+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool|_ThreadID=461;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5035:Unexpected exception while destroying resource from pool jdbc. Exception message: Error while destroying resource :I/O-Fehler: Socket read timed out|#]
```

Followed by (removed non relevant parts from my impl with ....)

```
   #|2015-10-23T16:35:00.087+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource|_ThreadID=576;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5031:System Exception
   javax.resource.spi.LocalTransactionException: Getrennte Verbindung
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.LocalTransactionImpl.rollback(LocalTransactionImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.ConnectorXAResource.rollback(ConnectorXAResource.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.rollback(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:571)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.rollback(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:893)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5126)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4915)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy248.loadData(Unknown Source)
       ....
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1663.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
       ....
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1559.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1563.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4058)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Getrennte Verbindung
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3921)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.LocalTransactionImpl.rollback(LocalTransactionImpl.java:128)
    ... 50 more
```

I have programmatic fail safe which opens a new transaction to avoid a ManagedException within in my application and retries three times in case of failure.

However this is apparently to not enough to ensure the stability of the JDBC connection.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what I tried and worked.

1. [IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574414/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection)
   -> Database was running, URL was correct, Firewall was tested with a custom ping script
2. [java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind (JBOSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947555/java-net-socketexception-unrecognized-windows-sockets-error-0-jvm-bind-jboss) -> The pc was a win7 machine however the argument -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true didn't help
3. [The network adapter could not establish the connection - Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037440/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-oracle-11g) -> Replaced my original jdbc 6 Jar with new one listed above, didn't solve the problem
4. [Java JDBC connection status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764671/java-jdbc-connection-status) -> This got my thinking

After seeing the post in 4. I tried several configurations in Resources -> JDBC ->  JDBC Connection Pools -> jdbc for timeouts etc. I though using

```
select 1 from SOME_TABLE;
```

to be the solution. Unfortunately I made the mistake use it like this

[image: Wrong configuration]

Instead of this

[image: Right configuration]

The difference by my understanding is that the first validates the connection when it goes into the pool. The second validates it when it's given out the pool to be used by a resource.

Now it seems to work fine.

I hope this helps!