# TLS1.2 support in jboss

Tags: java, https, tls1.2, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to connect to a remote web service from jboss EAP7.  The service uses TLS1.2.  I keep getting a socket read error when attempting to connect.  Here is the jboss debug tracing for https:

The certificate of the site I am trying to access:

```
  Subject: CN=*.smartpayform.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
  Issuer:  CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc2d0a153e5915039e88cbf7
  Valid from Mon Sep 05 12:33:58 EDT 2016 until Wed Sep 06 12:33:58 EDT 201
```

Log details:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false

Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session

*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1500947679 bytes = { 38, 123, 233, 142, 221, 57, 138, 148, 52, 147, 181, 100, 27, 32, 49, 149, 28, 31, 13, 15, 57, 208, 135, 179, 123, 104, 0, 151 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]

Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, HA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 191
0000: 01 00 00 BB 03 03 59 77   A5 DF 26 7B E9 8E DD 39  ......Yw..&....9
0010: 8A 94 34 93 B5 64 1B 20   31 95 1C 1F 0D 0F 39 D0  ..4..d. 1.....9.
0020: 87 B3 7B 68 00 97 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  ...h....:.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 58 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......X...4.2...
0070: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0080: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0090: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
00A0: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   16 00 14 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 04   02 02 03 02 01 02 02     ...............
default task-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 191
[Raw write]: length = 196
0000: 16 03 03 00 BF 01 00 00   BB 03 03 59 77 A5 DF 26  ...........Yw..&
0010: 7B E9 8E DD 39 8A 94 34   93 B5 64 1B 20 31 95 1C  ....9..4..d. 1..
0020: 1F 0D 0F 39 D0 87 B3 7B   68 00 97 00 00 3A C0 23  ...9....h....:.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
0050: C0 2D C0 31 00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
0060: C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 58 00 0A 00 34  ...........X...4
0070: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0080: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0090: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
00A0: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 0D 00 16 00 14  ................
00B0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 04 02 02 03  ................
00C0: 02 01 02 02                                        ....
default task-7, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
default task-7, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
default task-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
default task-7, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

You will see that *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2 was sent. However, when I look at a wireshark trace, It shows an SSL clientHelo instead of TLS.
      [image]

Comment: Have you added the certificate of the server you're connecting to into the truststore used by JBoss (`cacerts` by default)? It may be that the CA cert is not in `cacerts` (depending on the Java version you're using).

Comment: Yup.  That is the first few lines in the posting above.

Comment: At ClientHello time the actual protocol version has not yet been determined, and Wireshark List pane displays only the category. Looking at the Details pane, or the Raw pane, or the 'Raw write' in your trace, you can see the client is offering 1.2 (wire 0303). If you are actually interested the **server reset**, you might look at the numerous existing Qs that suggest a **likely cause nowadays is lack of SNI** (Server Name Indication), which in Java depends on the libraries and/or code you use to request the connection, about which your Q gives no hint.

Comment: If your server is indeed smartpayform.com = 99.198.117.131, a quick test with openssl shows it does reject a connection attempt without SNI, and accept one with (although at HTTP level it rejects my dummy HEAD / request).

Comment: Thanks I will review this suggestions.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085.  You were 100% correct.  Bug in JDK 1.8 - http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8144566 . Workaround - http://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html?_sm_au_=iVVSqQj0vD2FwQNv.  IF you want to post as an answer, please do so I can check it.